# Why am I getting a thread exception in my graphics program?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, graphics

**Quesiton:** So I am trying to create a program in which a ball bounces back and forth on a JFrame (this will later become more heavy, so I am using Canvas). However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error along with a blank window: (Any help would be GREATLY appreciated)

**Error:**

```
  Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLGraphicsConfig.createCompatibleImage(CGLGraphicsConfig.java:200)
    at java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(GraphicsConfiguration.java:178)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.getBackupImage(SunVolatileImage.java:236)
    at sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager.getBackupSurface(VolatileSurfaceManager.java:263)
    at sun.awt.image.VolatileSurfaceManager.initialize(VolatileSurfaceManager.java:126)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:88)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:98)
    at sun.awt.image.SunVolatileImage.<init>(SunVolatileImage.java:109)
    at sun.java2d.opengl.CGLGraphicsConfig.createBackBufferImage(CGLGraphicsConfig.java:356)
    at sun.lwawt.LWCanvasPeer.createBuffers(LWCanvasPeer.java:62)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:4016)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3956)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4479)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3833)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3756)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)
    at gpractice.Window.render(Window.java:37)
    at gpractice.Window.run(Window.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here is my code for my main Window class and my Prisoner class:

**Code for Window Class**

```
 public class Window extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    static Window game = new Window();
    static Prisoner pris;
    static Cop cop;
    static Boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Sucks!");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.add(game);
        game.start();
    }
    public void init(){
        cop = new Cop();
        pris = new Prisoner();
    }
    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        } 
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //Background///////////////
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
        ///////////////////////////
        pris.render(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

}
    public void run() {
        init();
        while (running){
        render();
        }
        stop();
    }
    private synchronized void start() {
        if (running){
            return;
        }
        else{
            running = true;
        }
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
    }
    private void stop() {
        if (!running){
            return;
        }
        else{
            running = false;
        }
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

**Code for Prisoner Class**

```
public class Prisoner {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int dx, dy=0;
    Cop cop = new Cop();

    public  Prisoner(){
        x = 250;
        y = 200;
        dx = 1;
        dy = 1;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
        move();
    }
    public void move(){

        if (x <= 0){
            dx = 1;
        }
        if (y <= 0){
            dy = 1; 
        }
        if (x >= 550){
            dx = -1; 
        }
        if (y >=430){
            dy = -1;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

}
```

**Code from Cop class (will be used in the future so not much in it)**

```
public class Cop {
private int x;
private int y; 
public Cop()
{
    x = 0;
    y=  0;
}
public void render(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
}
```

Comment: isn't the error self-explanatory?

Comment: For me it is not. What does it mean when it states invalid height and width that cannot be <= 0? @JunedAhsan

Comment: I never set the Width or Height less than or = 0 anywhere in the program?

Comment: Can you provide Cop class?

Comment: yes of course. @Ye Win. It will be used in the future but not ATM.

Comment: "frame.add(game)"; game is an instance of Window. @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: if it is self-explanatory, then please explain to someone who does not understand @JunedAhsan

Comment: Yes I was fooled by `Window` which is already a name used by `awt`. You never set the size of it, you added it to the frame but the layout is unable to determine the size of it. I suggest you to implement `getPreferredSize` in your Window class. Please also rename your class to something else than `Window` (ex: `MyWindow` or better `MyCanvas`).

Comment: It's possible that `render` is called before the frame is displayed on the screen

Comment: I did this as well as getPreferred size but neither changed anything @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: Ok that does sound like a possibility. Not sure why the question was down voted, I just do not understand the error. How would fix this? Some sort of delay? @MadProgrammer

Comment: `static` really isn't friend in this context

Comment: It works well for me. @MadProgrammer is certainly on the right track : some race condition is hidden.

Comment: To add the canvas to the JFrame, the instance has to be static though correct? Just realized stop() method was not synchronized so I changed it. However, still no difference. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @imgolden62 Works for me, but I would ensure that the frame is created within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: So if it works for you two, but not for me, is it my computer or some sort of build path error? Other programs similar to this work fine. @MadProgrammer

Comment: The cause of your problems is here: `new JFrame("Java Sucks!");`.  The Java compiler has obviously taken offence.  You are lucky it hasn't reformatted your disk ;-)

Comment: Haha @Stephen C that was a symptom of frustrationitis

Comment: Again I agree with @MadProgrammer: use invokeLater to create your GUI and to create your accessory thread to ensure that everything is ready before trying to draw. And no, the instance of `Window` has not to be static, you can use `frame.add(new Window());` if you want.

Comment: Yes ... well ... you are better of keeping that kind of thing out of public postings.

Comment: How would I start the game by calling game.start(); if game is not static? @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: Point noted. @StephenC

Comment: `Window w = new Window(); frame.add(w); w.start()`

Comment: Ok before they were global variables, so now as you suggested, I instantiated them inside the main method (otherwise a non static global Window instance resulted in an error when trying to add it to the frame and calling start. Still no change. @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: But then once its in the main method, its static soo.. @Jean-BaptisteYunes

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I am not sure how to further minimize this post. It works for others apparently but not me. Sorry to make you down vote it.

Comment: *"I am not sure how to further minimize this post."*  There are 4 letters in MCVE.  Look at the meaning of the ***other three letters.***  Note also that an MCVE might be more than one class, but should be only 1 Source file (so only 1 **`public`** class).  An MCVE should also include the imports.

Comment: Ok so in the future, If I need to display two public classes? should i just stick the second class inside the driver? Thanks @AndrewThompson

Comment: *"If I need to display two public classes?"*  For the purposes of making an MCVE, just demote one to default access and paste it into the end of the other.  Not every type of problem can be reduced down to a 'one source file' MCVE, but that is the ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you "start" the game, make sure that the window has been properly realised (attached to a native peer) and sized.

You should also make sure that the UI is created within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Sucks!");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.add(game);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setFocusable(true);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    game.start();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Because a frame also includes the frame decorations, the viewable may be small then the physical window size, instead of relying on magic numbers, you should values taken from the component itself

Make use of `getPreferredSize` to give the window's layout manager some idea what size you would like your component and `JFrame#pack` to pack the window around the contents...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600, 500);
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    //Background///////////////
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());
    ///////////////////////////
    pris.render(g);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}
```

Also, remove the `static` declarations, they are really dangerous and become problematic as the complexity of your code increases, instead of creating the UI within the `static main`, use some other non-static driver to initialise the UI

```
public class MyAwesomeGame {

    public static void main() {
        new MyAwesomeGame()
    }

    public MyAwesomeGame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Window game = new Window();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Sucks!");
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.add(game);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setFocusable(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                            game.start();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What would be an example of a non static driver? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Wow that's clever. Just create everything in the constructor and then invoke it in the main method. Ok you are awesome. Thank you @MadProgrammer